# Disable ALL session remembering functions of vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I prevent VS code from remembering ANYTHING from the last session?

I have following settings set:

- files.hotExit = off
- workbench.editor.restoreViewState = off
- window.restoreWindows = none
- workbench.startupEditor = newUntitledFile

And yet, when I open a project folder, VS Code will still re-open all files from the previous session in that folder. Is that just a hardcoded behavior?

This is with VS Code OSS 1.56.2.

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible at the moment, but there is a (long standing) feature request for this on VS Code's github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22613